# Exception in thread "main", What does this mean?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error

I'm working on a homework problem for class. Where you have to calculate the distance between two points. The code is basically done, but I have one question. When I enter q to end the loop. I get a message back.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q"

at.sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unkown Source)

at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unkown Source)

atDistance.main(Distance.java:11)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Distance {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true){
        System.out.print("Enter coordinate for x1: ");
        String x1String = input.next();
        if (x1String == "q")
            break;
            double x1 = Double.parseDouble(x1String);

        System.out.print("Enter coordinate for y1: ");
        String y1String = input.next();
        if (y1String == "q")
            break;
            double y1 = Double.parseDouble(y1String);

        System.out.print("Enter coordinate for x2: ");
        String x2String = input.next();
        if (x2String == "q")
            break;
            double x2 = Double.parseDouble(x2String);

        System.out.print("Enter coordinate for y2: ");
        String y2String = input.next();
        if (y2String == "q")
            break;
            double y2 = Double.parseDouble(y2String);

        double distance = (Math.pow(x2 - x1,2)) + (Math.pow(y2 - y1,2));
        distance = Math.sqrt(distance);
        System.out.printf("The distance is %5.2f",distance);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}//main
}//Distance
```

That is the code I have written. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do a string compare with ==. The "==" comparison checks to see if they are the exact same objects, not if the strings contain the same characters. Try `x1String.equals("q")` instead.

What's happening now is that the "==" will say "these aren't the same object" and then it will attempt to parse the "q" as a double in the next line, which is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

It means 'q' is not a number. To compare strings you have to use `equals`, `==` just compares references.

Answer (score 0):

This old chestnut...

You **can not** compare Strings (safely) using `==`. Use `.equals()` instead:

```
if (x1String.equals("q")) // change every == to .equals()
```

Java != Javascript

Answer (score 0):

`x1String == "q"` simply compares references. In order to compare the input string with the string `"q"`, you need to use `compareTo` or `equals`:

```
if (x1String.compareTo("q") == 0)
// or
if (x1String.equals("q"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you should be using a function such as `equals` to compare the contents of the objects (`x1String` and `"q"`) rather than comparing the actual objects/references, but you should also be checking if the string is numeric and/or `catch`ing any exceptions that are thrown by `parseDouble`.

What if someone inputs `"asdfg"`?